# Listing all my kafka consumers informations

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to list all my kafka consumers and inspect their state, group ...

Before I was using just spring-kafka so I did the following and it works

```
private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

var listenerContainers = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers();

    listenerContainers.forEach(mlc -> {

        var isRunning = mlc.isRunning();
        var group = mlc.getGroupId()
        // other checks
```

But now when I am using spring-cloud-stream with kafka, `listenerContainers` is an empty list !

How can I do the same with SCS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Cloud Stream, add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean and capture each listener container (e.g. store them in a list).

```java
List<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> containers = new ArrayList<>();

@Bean
ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
    return (container, dest, group) -> this.containers.add(container);
}
```